# Why goland 1.0 EAP tips "#command-line-arguments undefined: NewServer"

Tags: go, intellij-idea, hyperledger-fabric, delve, goland

When I debug the fabric source code  orderer module with Goland 1.0 EAP IDE, it could debug and tips that:

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec #gosetup
GOPATH=/Users/friends/Documents/VirtualMachine/share/gopath #gosetup
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/bin/go build -i -o /private/var/folders/cg/mwzlhrjs5y55ny553g6xz9tr0000gn/T/___orderer_start -gcflags "-N -l" /Users/friends/Documents/VirtualMachine/share/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go #gosetup

# command-line-arguments
orderer/main.go:76: undefined: NewServer
orderer/main.go:207: undefined: createLedgerFactory
```

the debug configurations is as following:
[image]

in the fact ,NewServer exists in the server.go 
[image]

When I delete server.go and util.go, and move the code to main.go.It works. I think it may be GoLand 1.0 EAP BUG.

Comment: Hard to say without sources. Possibly not imported or called without prefix like `server.NewSeever`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Run Configuration screenshot, the Run Kind value is a File. That means GoLand will run that file only. Change it to Package and it change the package name option, which will now appear to point to the right package, in that case, github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer

Comment: Thank you very much. And other way is to set the full orderer path with Directory.